# Requesting refresh token fails.No refresh tokens were found in the token store

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to get refresh token for Google from App Services,but I can't.

Log says

> 2016-11-04T00:04:25  PID[500] Verbose     Received request: GET https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google?access_type=offline
>   2016-11-04T00:04:25  PID[500] Verbose     Downloading OpenID configuration from https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
>
> 2016-11-04T00:04:25  PID[500] Verbose     Downloading OpenID issuer keys from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
>
> 2016-11-04T00:04:25  PID[500] Information Redirecting: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=299597639...04000925%26redir%3D&access_type=offline
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:17  PID[500] Verbose     Received request: GET https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google/callback?state=nonce%3D5656e1dd...&prompt=none
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:17  PID[500] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP endpoint POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token.
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:18  PID[500] Information Login completed for 'xxxxx@gmail.com'. Provider: 'google'.
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:18  PID[500] Verbose     Writing 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 728.
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:18  PID[500] Information Redirecting: https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token=%7B%22authenti...d6ffa9924e5%22%7D%7D
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:50  PID[500] Verbose     Received request: GET https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/.auth/refresh
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:50  PID[500] Verbose     JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:4fd4f6...', Issuer: 'https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/'.
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:50  PID[500] Warning     The refresh request issued by sid:4fd4f6... failed because no refresh tokens were found in the token store.
>
> 2016-11-04T00:05:50  PID[500] Information Sending response: 403.80 Forbidden

There seem to be no refresh tokens in token store,but why?
I turned on token store setting on portal already.

Answer (score 0):

If Google detects that it has already given your user a refresh token, then it will not give additional refresh tokens unless you explicitly prompt the user for consent.  You can do this by adding the **prompt=consent** query string parameter to the login URL. In your case, https://noteappsvr.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/google?access_type=offline&prompt=consent

Try this and see if that restores the Google refresh token.

Google documentation on this behavior can be found here (under the HTTP/REST tab): https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline

> **Important**: When your application receives a refresh token, it is important to store that refresh token for future use. If your application loses the refresh token, it will have to re-prompt the user for consent before obtaining another refresh token. If you need to re-prompt the user for consent, include the prompt parameter in the authorization code request, and set the value to consent.

In normal usage, the refresh token should not be lost. Let me know if you are seeing a case where it does get lost.

Comment: Thank you for your response,I can receive refresh token again by adding the prompt=consent parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your response,I can receive refresh token again by adding the prompt=consent parameter.

But adding this parameter always isn't recommended?
In practical usage,first urge the user to log in with dialog, then use refresh token several times.If it expires, show login dialog again.
There seems to be no problem to add that parameter at first.not?

Comment: I suggest you do the normal login and refresh flows as you have been. If refresh fails and your code detects that there is no refresh token, then perhaps you can invoke the prompt=consent to recreate the refresh token.